# Why do I get NullPointerException when trying to instantiate Mediaplayer? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

```
package com.oyly.gpsdemo
import android.content.Context
import android.media.MediaPlayer

class SoundGenerator(context: Context) : MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    private var mediaPlayer:    MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
    private var nextSound:      Int = R.raw.coast

    init {
        try { mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.coast) }
        catch (ex : Exception) { println("lyseoy11: $ex") }
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this)
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener (this)
    }
        override fun onPrepared(p0: MediaPlayer) {mediaPlayer.start()}
        override fun onCompletion(p0: MediaPlayer?) { playSound() }
        fun queueSound(resid: Int) {
            nextSound = resid
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying) playSound()
        }
        fun playSound() {
            mediaPlayer.reset()
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(resources.openRawResourceFd(nextSound))
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()
        }
}
```

The "mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.coast" line throws the following exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

I have moved this code from a standalone app, where it worked, into this class of another app. Now it doesn't work and I can't understand why. The MediaPlayer.Create() method takes as arguments the context (which I pass on from the MainActivity class that calls this class), and an uri to the audio file to be played. Neither of them are null.

Why do I get this exception?

**Edit:**

The only place SoundGenerator is created is in the MainActivity Initializer:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private             var soundGenerator : SoundGenerator = SoundGenerator(this)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you add all the places where you create `SoundGenerator` too in the question (the relevant code from `MainActivity`)? I don't see how you could get that error unless the context was null. Also include where you define the variable that holds it in MainActivity if it is a class member. Does the activity do something like `private val sound = SoundGenerator(this)`?

Comment: Maybe it's some issue with R class, make sure this code is in the same package with rest of your code, including IDE-generated R.

Comment: What if you try waiting to initialize SoundGenerator until onCreate in the main activity? I think some context related things aren't set up immediately.

Comment: @TylerV Thanks, that did it. I changed it to:     private lateinit    var soundGenerator                  : SoundGenerator and in the onCreate: soundGenerator = SoundGenerator(this). I'll accept as solution if you want to write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often it is best to wait to use the activity as a context until later in the lifecycle when things have been set up (e.g. in `onCreate`) to avoid initialization order issues. For exampe:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var soundGenerator : SoundGenerator

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //...
        soundGenerator = SoundGenerator(this)
    }
}
```

Alternately, sometimes you can use `applicationContext` instead of the current activity as an appropriate context.